# Angular reactive form returning same value many times

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

i'm doing a console.log in order to print a needed value.. i'm doing exactly this way

`console.log(this.orderForm.get('addressId')?.value);`

it's expected to be printed a single value, but that's not my case..
it has being printing the value so many times..
I need this value to search an address in an array, just like

`this.addresses.find(x => x.id == this.orderForm.get('addressId')?.value);`

but as I'm receiving it so many times, the find()/filter() method is breaking..

I guess it's something related to subscribe/unsubscribe, but haven't find anything about this on web..

ps: this method is in my html code just like
`<span> getAddress() </span>`

Comment: https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this function

```html
<span>getAddress()</span>
```

you are in HTML, so it will update regularly according to the form.

You can update as follows:

```html
<span (click)="getAddress()"> Click here! </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below like

```
this.addresses.find(x => x.id === (this.orderForm.get('addressId')?.value));
```

instead of

```
this.addresses.find(x => x.id == this.orderForm.get('addressId')?.value);
```

Hope it should be work!